# get text from url list to csv

Tags: csv, wget

i need retrieve text from url list.
I have csv (about 150 000 rows) with ID and URL. On this URL is just plain text without HTML code.
I need write this text to csv with ID from input csv.
Its this possible with wget for example?

Input CSV

> 9788075020536|http://pemic-books.cz/ASPX/Annotation.aspx?kod=0180853

Output CSV

> 9788075020536|Učebnice je dílem kolektivu autorů katedry ústavního práva Právnické fakulty Univerzity Karlovy v Praze a externích spolupracovníků. V souladu s tradičním pojetím ústavního práva je obecná státověda podávána jako jeho vstupní a neoddělitelná součást. Kniha je reprintem původního vydání z roku 1998, v nakladatelství Leges vychází poprvé. Na učebnici navazuje Ústavní právo a státověda, 2. díl, Ústavní právo České republiky, který byl vydání nakladatelstvím Leges v roce 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following columns

curlcsv file contents:

```
0001|columnbefore1|https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=2&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new|columnafter1
0002|columnbefore2|https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=3&max=4&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new|columnafter2
0003|columnbefore3|https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=5&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new|columnafter3
```

Here are the "one-liners" you could use:

- ### gawk:

  ```
  gawk ' {
      match($0, /^(([^|]+[|]){2})([^|]+)([|][^|]+)*$/, arr); 
      req = "curl -s \""arr[3]"\"";
      req | getline res;
      print arr[1]""res""arr[4];
  }
  ' curlcsv >result
  ```

  `/^(([^|]+[|]){2})` - 2 here means skip 2 columns (in your case skip 1 column)

  `([^|]+)` - get the contents of the url column

  `([|][^|]+)*` - save the rest column values

  **result** file would look like this:

  ```
  0001|columnbefore1|2|columnafter1
  0002|columnbefore2|3|columnafter2
  0003|columnbefore3|5|columnafter3
  ```

  this approach would hit limits on open files (see JaromírHeimlich comment below)

  solution to this limitation problem could be:

  ```
  split -l 100 curlcsv && ls | grep -v curlcsv | xargs -n 1 gawk ' {
      match($0, /^(([^|]+[|]){2})([^|]+)([|][^|]+)*$/, arr); 
      req = "curl -s \""arr[3]"\"";
      req | getline res;
      print arr[1]""res""arr[4];
  }
  ' >>../result
  ```

  place curlcsv to an empty folder since `split` would create a lot of partial lists in that directory.
- ### sed:

  ```
  cat curlcsv | sed -e 's/^\(\([^|]\+[|]\)\{2\}\)\([^|]\+\)\([|][^|]\+\)*$/echo "\1"$(curl -s "\3")"\4"/' | bash >result
  ```

  `/^(([^|]+[|]){2})` - 2 here means skip 2 columns (in your case skip 1 column)

  In this example sed constructs the bash script to get the result.

  Since this solution generates bash commands, it doesn't have the limitation problem of the gawk solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use gawk. Just 1 more problem occurs. On about row 3500 its stop with error: fatal: cannot open pipe `curl -s "http://pemic-books.cz/ASPX/Annotation.aspx?kod=0117551"' (too many files open). Trying to figure out.

Comment: @JaromírHeimlich one solution here could be to split the file `split -l 1000 src_file && ls | grep -v src_file | xargs -n 1 ../replace_script.sh` (and use >>result to append) or maybe "--connect-timeout SECONDS" flag for the curl command could help.

Comment: @JaromírHeimlich timeout doesn't work, curl creates a new connection but finished curls are still present in the processes list, os hits the soft limit on opened files. Solution here could be a tool that would reuse connections or prefetching data with "curl url1 url2 ..." and replacing urls with data in the source list. Not sure which option would be easier to perform.

Comment: @JaromírHeimlich by the way, sed version doesn't have that kind of problem.